# Why will my ng-grid footer not align to my bottom border

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid and other AngularJS UI Bootstrap elements. I finally was able to reproduce a problem I am having in my site. Here is the Plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/i2RwJ0peJyvuF1IgHEWJ?p=preview).

Notice the red border down at the bottom of the footer between the footer and the border. I have found that if I comment out the Bootstrap CSS, the problem goes away. Evidently there is a conflict, though I am not sure where to start looking.

Is this a known problem with ng-grid? Can ng-grid be used on a page where UI Bootstrap is being used?

[image: Screenshot of problem.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the root cause of the issue is, but if you just need a fix, add to your css:

```
.ngFooterPanel {
  top: 2px;
}
```

or

```
.ngFooterPanel {
  height: 57px;
}
```

Comment: You're right! That does work. OK, I get why changing the height 2px larger covers up the red, but why does changing the *top* of the ngFooterPanel to 2px push it down? So weird. I'll take it though!

Comment: it's position: relative, so when you set top to 2px it just says to move it 2px from the top of wherever it was before (effectively move it down 2px)